# What size plate for 2 1-gang boxes side by side

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

Whoever put the electrical boxes in our kitchen before we moved in put two separate 1-gang boxes side by side (an outlet and a toggle) instead of just using a 2-gang box. The plates covering them were two single plates that had the edges cut off so they could butt up against each other.

I would like to replace the plate, but a standard plate won't fit. The outlet and toggle are about 1/2" too far apart for a standard plate to fit. Is there a specific plate made for this kind of configuration or will I have to just install a new 2-gang box and patch around it? If there is a larger plate, what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Whoever installed the boxes didn't learn how to do electrical work properly. So consequently, you have two single plates that have been trimmed.

If you were to find a plate like this it would be a custom item and may cost more than it is worth.

Either you will have to keep the trimmed plates, or you will have to replace the two single gang boxes with a 2-gang box.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly this. Seen it a few times and always gets me angry. This is why people need to know what they are doing before they do it.

Comment: Shoot, that's what I was afraid of. How difficult is it to replace the two with a 2-gang? I've installed lighting and the usual minor stuff like that and it doesn't seem too difficult, but since I've never done it, I'm not sure.

Comment: And yeah, the contractor the flipper used obviously didn't have a clue. All our tile started coming up a few months after we moved in because they didn't use an underlayment to stabilize the subfloor.

Comment: It depends on how they fastened the boxes into the wall. If they are nailed to the studs it will make it more difficult. If they are old-work boxes (just fastened into the drywall) it will be easier. Either way, you will have to repair some drywall after replacing the boxes. The boxes should have enough wire to move an inch or so.